# How to mouse over then mouse out properly with two separate frames in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have some AS3 I am trying to write in order to create a mouse over/mouse out of an information image.

I have two frames, one of them has a button shaped as a circle with an "i" in it for information and frame two has the same button, slightly different colour with a big speech bubble next to it.

I need to set it so that by default it shows frame 1, when you mouse over it goes to frame two and stops and then when you mouse off the "i" button it goes back to frame 1.

```
movieClip_1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverInfoButton);

function mouseOverInfoButton (e:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(2);
}

movieClip_1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutInfoButton);

function mouseOutInfoButton (e:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called `gotoAndStop` of your `this` object in both `mouseOverInfoButton` and `mouseOutInfoButton`. To change the frame of `movieClip_1` you need to call `gotoAndStop` on that movie clip.

`movieClip_1.gotoAndStop(1); // or 2 in other case`

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm basically new to AS3 could you explain a bit more? Sorry!

Comment: Are you familiar with basic Object Oriented Programming concepts? If not then it's difficult for me to explain in few words here. Sorry.